# Best voltage for a Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have 5.0V 3A and 5.2V 3A regulated supplies that I can repurpose for my Raspberry Pi 3B project. Am thinking of using the USB power jack. Which should I go with?

5.2V would seem to be within the specs but is there any benefit over 5.0V?

Answer (score 1):

5.1 V is preferable if you are using a normal short cable.
5 Volt is good for a fast-charging cable.
5.2 V is good when you are using a poor quality of USB charger cable or a longer cable.
The voltage is sometimes increased because there might be some losses through the cable.
I gave you all the necessary information so far. You can now choose one easily.

Answer (score 0):

Both should be fine.

The 5.2V one may be better if you have a poor quality USB cable between the PSU and the Pi.  Some USB cables have flimsy wires and drop significant voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Both voltages are tolerated by the Raspberry Pi 3B, but official documentation actually suggests 5.1V.

Higher voltages usually mean more power if the amperage is the same. Also a higher voltage might give a little more heat output, but 0.1V is very negligible.

I suggest using the 5.2V as some of it will be lost to the inefficiencies of cabling.

Source: [Power Supply - Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md)